# Laravel Passport - Guest Token

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

Let's assume there is an application with 10 dynamic pages (probably forms) out of which, 8 pages are restricted (requires user to login in application) and 2 pages are available for anonymous users.

My front end application is in Angular 2 and back-end API is developed in Laravel 5.4. I'm more fascinated towards JWT tokens and found that, laravel has in-built support through passport.

**Questions:**

1. I can easily use [password grant tokens](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport#password-grant-tokens) for those 8 restricted page. But how do I give guest token to my Angular app for accessing those 2 pages
2. How can I restrict guest user for accessing API features of 8 restricted page. (Or how do I check if visited user is guest or logged in user at API end)

> **Note:** I cannot use [Personal Access Tokens](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport#personal-access-tokens) as it will allow my app to
>   use any restricted API feature.

Comment: [Token Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport#token-scopes) could be helpful to restrict user actions, so you could create one "global" access token for guest users that is send to every not authenticated user.

Comment: Looks interesting! I will explore more on it. Thanks Tek!

Comment: Did you find anything @SahilPurav? If so, could you please share what you did to cover this guest authentication mechanism. I'm in a similar situation to you.

Comment: Yes @AaronFahey Let me phrase my answer... Read it tomorrow :)

Comment: Thank you @SahilPurav :)

Comment: @AaronFahey Answer is posted. Let me know if it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used [JWT](https://jwt.io/) approach here. In my case, I created JWT token from my API. For those who wants to use JWT feature, they can take a look at [this package](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth). I added new payload called "Guest" and assigned boolean value to it. In my database, I added new user (called anonymous user) and stored the id of it in my laravel configuration.

Next, I created new middleware VerifyJwtToken, which validates the user, extracts it's payload (with base64_decode) and identify if it is guest. Now all of my Laravel routes are inside this middleware.

Next, I stored this token in laravel session as well as [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) (for accessing it through angular).

Now, I can easily access this token from localStorage. In the Angular end i used [Angular2Jwt](https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt) package which helps extracting the token and identifying if it is guest or logged in user. I also created [HTTP Interceptor](https://scotch.io/@kashyapmukkamala/using-http-interceptor-with-angular2) in Angular 4 which adds JWT token as header in every API requests.